# How can i use an already authenticated session for google calendar?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've implemented simple Google+ authentication on my MVC5 app and I'd like to access their google calendar. How do I do this using the MVC identity system and my already authenticated user?

```
Dim authGOps = New GooglePlusAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .Caption = "Google+",
        .ClientId = "MYCLIENTRID",
        .ClientSecret = "MYCLIENTSECRET",
        .Provider = New GooglePlusAuthenticationProvider() With {
            .OnAuthenticated = Async Function(context)
                                   context.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim(GooglePlusAccessTokenClaimType, context.AccessToken))
                               End Function
        }
    }


    authGOps.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")

    app.UseGooglePlusAuthentication(authGOps)
```

Getting the calendar service:

```
Dim calendarService = New CalendarService(New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
WHAT GOES HERE TO AUTHENTICATE USING MY OLD AUTH CEDENTIALS?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I as well would love to use the Service as it's documented almost everywhere, but I found a workaround to at least getting the data and not having to login again.

Make sure to Nuget Json.Net to deserialize and strongly type. Otherwise you'll get a Json string to manage.

It's in C#, but I'm sure the translation won't be too difficult. Hope it helps!

```
var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var claims = claimsIdentity.Claims;

var accessTokenClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == GooglePlusAccessTokenClaimType);

if (accessTokenClaim != null)
{
    string calendarUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(accessTokenClaim.Value);

    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(calendarUrl);
        var calendarList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalendarList>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```